# Formatting Numbers right aligned R, longer than longest number

Tags: r, format, printf

I need to format numbers right aligned with a fixed width left and right of the comma sign, regardless of the number. For example 3 digits left of the comma and two on the right. So that `12.3` would be formatted as `" 12.30"`. Best solution I came up with was this:

```
test <- c(10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0)

format(round(c(100,test), 2),
   justify = "right",
   scientific = FALSE,
   nsmall = 2)[-1]
```

Is there a way of archiving this directly with `format`, `printf`, `sprintf`, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
test <- c(10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0)
formatC(test, width = 6, digits = 2, format = "f")
#[1] " 10.00" "  1.00" "  0.10" "  0.01" "  0.00" "  0.00"
```

Obviously, this is a soft width specification. If you have more than three digits on the left, the width is increased to accommodate that:

```
formatC(100000, width = 6, digits = 2, format = "f")
#[1] "100000.00"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried many combinations of arguments to `format`,  `formatC`,  `printf`, `sprintf` didn't find this one.

Comment: I learned this by carefully reading the documentation in `help("formatC")`. I admit, `formatC` accepts quite a few parameters, but on the flip site it's pretty versatile. You can probably also do this with `sprintf`.